# strings do not match

Tags: excel, vba, string

Having the next text: "CLS (C218) 4 doors Coupe 10-16 with fixed points".
I have to save in a variable the start year(10) and the end year (16) as strings.The problem is that when I run the next code:

```
StartYr = Split(Years, "-")(0)

EndYr = Split(Years, "-")(1)
```

the `StartYr` will be "points" and `EndYr` will be empty. 
How can I change it that StartYr will be "10" and EndYr will be "10"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `StartYr` and `EndYr` will always be two digits numbers:

```
StartYr = Right(Split(Years, "-")(0), 2)
EndYr = Left(Split(Years, "-")(1), 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub getYears()
    Dim s As String, arr, arr2, a

    s = "CLS (C218) 4 doors Coupe 10-16 with fixed points"

    arr = Split(s, " ")
    For Each a In arr
        If InStr(a, "-") > 0 Then
            arr2 = Split(a, "-")
            MsgBox arr2(0) & vbCrLf & arr2(1)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next a
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This works as well, taking the `" " by default` - `arr = Split(s)`

Answer (score 1):

you can use also these methods instr and mid...In this case the result give you the number with two length like 10 and 16.

```
Sub test()
Dim pos As Integer
Dim s, s1, s2 As String

 s = "CLS (C218) 4 doors Coupehhhh 10-16 with fixed points"
pos = InStr(1, s, "-") ' get position of "-"
s1 = Mid(s, pos - 2, 2) 'get 10. find position "-"  come back of two position and take 2 chars
s2 = Mid(s, pos + 1, 2) 'get 16. find position "-" come ahead 1 position and take two chars
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this too.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vS, s1, s2
    Dim s  As String
    Dim StartYr As Integer
    Dim EndYr As Integer

    s = "CLS (C218) 4 doors Coupe 10-16 with fixed points"

    vS = Split(s, "-")
    s1 = Split(vS(0))
    s2 = Split(vS(1))

    StartYr = Trim(s1(UBound(s1)))
    EndYr = Trim(s2(LBound(s2)))
    MsgBox StartYr & vbCrLf & EndYr

End Sub
```